# Asp.net Json Post request

Tags: asp.net, json, vb.net, ssl

I need to connect to a server by sending a Json request.

The admin of the server told me that I should have an https server installed.

I bought an ssl and installed it on my server.

They sent me the json string format i.e. how to get the data from their server.
I tried to make an example request but each time I receive this error:

> The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.

I called them and they said that the request is missing the private or public key certificate (I send them the certificate and they installed it on their server also) but still get the same error.

This is the code I use:

Can anyone tell me if I have something wrong please?

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    POST("https://gw.bisan.com/api/apdemo_6", "{""user"":""MyUser"",""password"":""MyPASS"",""command"":""table"",""table"":""currency"",""fields"":[""symbol"",""rate""]}")
    ' Read()
End Sub

Private Sub POST(url As String, jsonContent As String)
    Try
        Dim request As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create(url), HttpWebRequest)
        request.ContentType = "text/json"
        request.Method = "POST"
        Dim streamWriter As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream())
        streamWriter.Write(jsonContent)
        streamWriter.Flush()
        streamWriter.Close()
        Dim httpResponse As HttpWebResponse = request.GetResponse()
        Dim streamReader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream())
        Dim result = streamReader.ReadToEnd()
        Label1.Text = result.ToString
    Catch ex As WebException
        Label1.Text = ex.Message
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: You need to see the post request (using fiddler or some other tools), and compare with their expected post.

Comment: can u explain more plz

Answer (score 1):

Install Fiddler on your development machine http://www.telerik.com/fiddler, launch it and make the post request from your machine.  Fiddler will catch all of the post request information and organize it for you so you can view exactly what is being sent by your code and compare it with what the server is expecting.  From there you should be able to easily see the 400 error causes more clearly and modify your code accordingly.

I would guess that the problem lies in the final output of the JSON string or the request.ContentType = "text/json" (maybe needs to be application/json).  Either way, Fiddler is a much quicker way to find out.

Answer (score 0):

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    POST("https://gw.bisan.com/api/apdemo_6", "{""user"":""MyUser"",""password"":""MyPASS"",""command"":""table"",""table"":""currency"",""fields"":[""symbol"",""rate""]}")
    ' Read()
End Sub

Private Sub POST(url As String, jsonContent As String)
    Try
        Dim request As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create(url), HttpWebRequest)
        request.ContentType = "application/json"
        request.Method = "POST"
        Dim streamWriter As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream())
        streamWriter.Write(jsonContent)
        streamWriter.Flush()
        streamWriter.Close()
        Dim httpResponse As HttpWebResponse = request.GetResponse()
        Dim streamReader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream())
        Dim result = streamReader.ReadToEnd()
        Label1.Text = result.ToString
    Catch ex As WebException
        Label1.Text = ex.Message
    End Try
End Sub
```